# eliminar cadenas iguales sucesivas

Tags: javascript

Mi codigo elimina las cadenas sucesivas cuando existe 2 cadenas iguales pero cuando existe mas, no elimina.

**Ejemplo con 2 cadenas sucesivas iguales** `"a", "a"`

```js
var string = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
eliminarVecinosRepetidos(string);

function eliminarVecinosRepetidos(cadenas) {
  for (var x = 0; x < cadenas.length; x++) {
    for (var i = x + 1; i < cadenas.length; i++) {
      if (cadenas[i] === cadenas[x]) {
        cadenas.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(cadenas);
  return cadenas;

}
```

**Ahora con 3** `"a","a","a"`

```js
var string = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
eliminarVecinosRepetidos(string);

function eliminarVecinosRepetidos(cadenas) {
  for (var x = 0; x < cadenas.length; x++) {
    for (var i = x + 1; i < cadenas.length; i++) {
      if (cadenas[i] === cadenas[x]) {
        cadenas.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(cadenas);
  return cadenas;

}
```

Comment: Se vale utilizar otra forma de realizar esa tarea o solo quieres saber porque la tuya falla?

Comment: @Einer quiero una buena solucion, solamente quiero cumplir con mi objetivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Utilizando [**`Array#reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)

Comprobando que el valor anterior es distinto al actual.

Utilizamos el segundo argumento del método reduce (`valorInicial`), que será una lista que se irá llenando en cada iteración con los valores que cumplan que el elemento anterior sea distinto.

```js
var array = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "a"]

var filtrado = array.reduce((res, val, idx, arr) => 
  (val != arr[idx - 1] && res.push(val) && res) || res, [])

console.log(filtrado)
```

---

#### Utilizando [**`Array#filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

De forma muy parecida pero más elocuente:

```js
var array = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "a"]

var filtrado = array.filter((el, idx, arr) => el != arr[idx - 1] )

console.log(filtrado)
```

Comment: me explicas esta parte && arr.push(val) && arr) || arr, [] porfavor

Comment: `(val != arr[idx - 1] && res.push(val) && res) || res, [])` es equivalente a `if(val != arr[idx-1]){ res.push(val); return res } else { return res }`

Comment: Ups, no era mi intención quitar reputación a nadie. Pero se agradece que marques mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo tienes en el segundo bucle:

- Encuentra el primer carácter `a` en el índice 0.
- Recorre el array a partir del índice 1
- Encuentra una `a` en el índice 1 y la elimina
- El array queda `["a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]`
- Comprueba el índice 2 en busca de una `a` (cuando debería volver a comprobar el 1)

Si restas uno al índice después del `splice` obtendrás el resultado deseado:

```js
var string = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
eliminarVecinosRepetidos(string);

function eliminarVecinosRepetidos(cadenas) {
  for (var x = 0; x < cadenas.length; x++) {
    for (var i = x + 1; i < cadenas.length; i++) {
      if (cadenas[i] === cadenas[x]) {
        cadenas.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(cadenas);
  return cadenas;

}
```

Aunque en realidad lo que hace el código es eliminar los caracteres de la posición siguiente hasta que es diferente o se llega al final del array. Así que mejor que con el `for` podrías hacer:

```js
var string = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
eliminarVecinosRepetidos(string);

function eliminarVecinosRepetidos(cadenas) {
  for (var x = 0; x < cadenas.length; x++) {
    while (x + 1 < cadenas.length && cadenas[x] === cadenas[x+1]){
      cadenas.splice(x + 1, 1);
    }
  }
  console.log(cadenas);
  return cadenas;

}
```

Otra opción más compacta: recorre una sola vez el array a partir de la segunda posición eliminando el carácter si es igual que el anterior:

```js
var string = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];
eliminarVecinosRepetidos(string);

function eliminarVecinosRepetidos(cadenas) {
  for (var i=1; i<cadenas.length; i++){
    if (cadenas[i] === cadenas[i-1]){
      cadenas.splice(i--,1);      
    }    
  }
  console.log(cadenas);
  return cadenas;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es verificar que el ultimo elemento del array que guardaras los elementos, no sea igual al elemento actual del array que le pases como parametro:

```js
var data = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "a"];

function eliminarVecinosRepetidos(data){
   var result = [];
   for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        if(result.length == 0 || result[result.length-1] != data[i]){
          result.push(data[i]);
        }
   }
   
   return result;
}

console.log(eliminarVecinosRepetidos(data));
```

`result.length == 0` verifica que el si es el primer elemento, siempre lo agregamos.

`result[result.length-1] != data[i]` lo que hace es verificar que el ultimo elemento no sea igual al elemento actual del array siendo procesado.

Comment: es justo lo que buscaba,

Comment: @Marcos no me di cuenta, hare la prueba, me puedes ayudar?

Comment: Aunque ya la aceptes, actualice mi respuesta acorde a tu pregunta. Gracias @Marcos por la observación.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías resolverlo así:

- Utilizamos [`array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach), para iterar el arreglo.
- Inicialmente comparamos la primer `cadena` contra vacio, ya que es la primera
- Si la `cadena` es distinta de la controlada, entonces la agregamos al arreglo de respuesta y la establecemos como la nueva cadena controlada.

#### Demo:

```js
console.log(eliminarVecinosRepetidos(["a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "a"]));

function eliminarVecinosRepetidos(words) {
  let result = [],
    check = '';
    
  words.forEach(function (word) {
    if (word == check) return;
    result.push(check = word);
  });
  return result;
}
```

---

### Update

También podrías usar [`array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

#### Demo:

```js
console.log(eliminarVecinosRepetidos(["a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "a"]));

function eliminarVecinosRepetidos(words) {
  let check = '';
  return words.filter(function(word) {
    return word != check ? check = word : false;
  });
}
```

Comment: @hubman, he actualizado mi respuesta con una segunda opción.